# Como alterar o background com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma função em javascript que retorna o dia e hora para texto, para inserção no html, como posso adicionar estilos a esse texto, devo fazer dentro do javascript ou mesmo no html

```
    function date_time(id){


    date = new Date;
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    months = new Array('Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outbro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');
    d = date.getDate();
    day = date.getDay();
    days = new Array('Domingo', 'Segunda - Feira', 'Terça - Feira', 'Quarta - Feira', 'Quinta - Feira', 'Sexta - Feira', 'Sabado');
    h = date.getHours();
    if(h<10)
    {
            h = "0"+h;
    }
    m = date.getMinutes();
    if(m<10)
    {
            m = "0"+m;
    }
    s = date.getSeconds();
    if(s<10)
    {
            s = "0"+s;
    }
    result = 'Bem Vindo, Hoje é '+days[day]+' '+d+' '+months[month]+' '+year;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
    setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
    return true;
    }
```

Html

```
    <span id="date_time"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = date_time('date_time');</script>
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que alterar o estilo desse span. Como ele já tem uma cor só mude ela: procure por [`#EC2028`](http://color.re/EC2028.png) (ou `rgb(236,32,40)`) no resto do código e troque pela cor que quiser.

Interpretando literalmente sua questão, use:

```
// Muda a cor do fundo:
document.getElementById('date_time').style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; // ou a cor que quiser

// Muda a cor do texto:
document.getElementById('date_time').style.color = 'black';
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `.style` para definir as propriedades [css](/questions/tagged/css) do elemento

Exemplo:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.color="blue";
```

Dessa forma você pode adicioanr quaisqur atributos [css](/questions/tagged/css) no seu elemento

Answer (score 0):

## Resposta:

Você tem 3 opções, das quais são elas:

**(1)** - Você pode alterar a cor do texto aplicando um estilo CSS ao seu elemento `<span>` que seria por exemplo:

```css
#date_time {
  color: #FFF; /*branco*/
}
```

**(2)** - Você também pode fazer via javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('date_time').style.color = '#fff';//codigo hexadecimal para branco
```

**(3)** - Você também pode implementar estilo diretamente aplicado ao elemento html (inline style) que seria no seu HTML:

```html
<span id="date_time" style="color:#FFF"></span>
```

## Explicação:

Um elemento HTML pode ter estilos aplicados a ele em diferentes formas, o navegador interpreta todos os estilos que estão com referência à seu elemento, pode haver sobreposição de estilos também, a mais importante será sempre a mais especifica, ou a que tiver a tag `!important`.

A solução mais recomendada é a **(1)** que seria aplicar um estilo CSS ao seu código CSS de sua página, pode ser um arquivo externo.css ou um `<style>`.

Porém você pode optar pelo o que for melhor para você.

Comment: Está resolvido, grande explicação Obrigado ;)

Comment: Concordo com o Paulo Roberto, acho melhor alterar no css é pra isso que ele serve :)

Answer (score -1):

Olá, eu juntei isso usando jquery, até pq não sei muito javascript, mas vc não poderia adicionar classes conforme horário? e tratar as cores e estilos conforme a classe adicionada?

Segue exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/alexmachado/8U5mE/

Comment: coloque pelo menos a parte do código Javascript aqui no SOPT. É bom ter um exemplo funcional, mas pelo menos o caroço da solução vale a pena manter na resposta.